# Notification Group Room message didn't show unread messages, only displays the browser notification

Tags: converse.js

How can I display unread messages like private chats..

Any new message to group room... didn't show the unread messages like private messages

[image]

Comment: I just created an issue on Github https://github.com/conversejs/converse.js/issues/2233

Answer (score 0):

This problem is marked as a bug in the issue tracker, so perhaps it will be fixed. Below is a workaround I've used using a plugin. What this does is it checks for a group message, and when received, adds a class to the minimized chat box. I added some example css with a style to blink the text in the box.

```js
    converse.plugins.add('myplugin', {
        initialize: function () {
            var c = this._converse;

            c.on('message', function (m) {
                if (m.stanza.textContent!='' && m.attrs.type == 'groupchat') {
                    $('.chat-head-chatroom').addClass('alert-room');
                }
            });

        }
    });

    converse.initialize({
       ...
      whitelisted_plugins: ['myplugin'],
      ...
```

CSS Code:

```css
.alert-room {
    font-weight: bold !important;
}

    .alert-room .restore-chat {
        animation: blinker 1s linear infinite;
    }

@keyframes blinker {
    50% {
        opacity: 0.5;
    }
}
```